# What happens if I use the same id for several widgets in different layouts?

Tags: android, layout

Currently I am careful to use different IDs for each widget, but if I used the same id for some widgets in different layout xml files, what would happen to my calls to findViewById?  Would it get confused and return a widget from the wrong layout file?

I ask because I was thinking  of including a view (with a row of buttons) in some other  views, then each of those screen classes would have to assign a slightly different behavior to each button on the included view.  But to do that they would be calling findViewById on the same id.
For instance currently  I do like this in each file:

```
final ImageButton homeButton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rshome_button);
homeButton.setOnClickListener(new BottomButtonClickListener());

final ImageButton hotButton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rshotlist_button);
hotButton.setOnClickListener(new BottomButtonClickListener());

final ImageButton locButton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rsbot_map);
locButton.setOnClickListener(new BottomButtonClickListener());

final ImageButton sendButton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.rssend_button);
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new BottomButtonClickListener());
```

But I change the R.id in each file to point to the widget in each assiciated layout.  it would be nice if I could use the one R.id for all so I don't have to tweak every layout file and every screen class.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fine as long as you don't instantiate both layouts in the same activity. But having never tried it I wouldn't like to guarantee it.

However, I wouldn't be surprised if the Android code generator errors out though, as it will probably try to create two `R.id.rshome_button` entries in your *R.java* file.

Comment: So how it know which one is the one we are looking?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use the same `id`s in different layouts. In fact, it may be good practice to.

Answer (score -1):

The best way you try it yourself.

But you do setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

So if you call findViewById it will be looked for a widget with given id in your_layout

That's why you can use same id's in different layouts.

Comment: R.id.view_id is a static integer generated at compile time, before setContentView() runs.